# elastic query returns same results after insert

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm using elasticsearch.js to move a document from one index to another.

1a) Query index_new for all docs and display on the page.
1b) Use query of index_old to obtain a document by id.
2) Use an insert to index_new, inserting result from index_old.
3) Delete document from index_old (by id).

4) Requery index_new to see all docs (including the new one). However, at this point, it returns the same list of results as returned in 1a. Not including the new document.

Is this because of caching? When I refresh the whole page, and 1a is triggered, the new document is there.. But not without a refresh.

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the segments merging and refreshing that happens inside the elasticsearch indexes per shard and replica.

Whenever you are writing to the index wou never write to the original index file but rather write to newer smaller files called **segment** which then gets merged into the bigger file in background batch jobs.

Next question that you might have is 
**How often does this thing happen or how can one have a control over this**

1. There is a setting in the index level configuration called **refresh_interval**. It can have multiple values depending upon the kind of strategy that you want to use.

   refresh_interval -

-1  : To stop elasticsearch handle the merging and you control at your end with the **_refresh** API in elasticsearch.

X : x is an integer and has a value in seconds. Hence elasticsearch will refresh all the indexes every x seconds.

2. If you have replication enabled into your indexes then you might also experience in result value toggling. This happens just because the indexes have multiple shard and a shard has multiple replicas. Hence different replicas have different window pattern for refreshing. Hence while querying the query actually routes to different shard replicas in the meantime which shows different states in the time window.

Hence if you are using a setting to set periods of refresh interval then assume to have a consistent state in next X to 2X seconds at **max**.

[Segment Merge Background details](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/merge-process.html)

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/indices-update-settings.html

Comment: Two minor comments: You might want to look into [`refresh=wait_for´](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-refresh.html) and if you do a fetch by ID, it will always get the latest version (does a forced refresh in the background in 5.x+; before it read the value from the translog)